# SQL Server 2005 - T-SQL - How to generate int ID?

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have faced a thing as NEWID(). I thought it should be useful as to insert INT key id-s values to a table, but it returns float or something which is not pretty good for ID column value. So my question is how to get auto generated INT ID value for table insert?

Comment: Do you need to know the next ID value for a table before you insert the row?  Would it not work to get the ID after inserting a row (SQL should auto-increment the ID by default) using @@IDENTITY?

Comment: `newid()` generates a GUID. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

Comment: Well, of course, I want all ID values be different but here I am not sure how big the table is expected to be so I need to gen big different numbers during the whole insert life cycle... How to do that?

Comment: @therealmitchconnors, you want to use the OUTPUT clause to return the identity value or scope_identity() not @@identity which will can return the incorrect value under certain conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You define a column of type `INT` (or `SMALLINT, TINYINT, BIGINT`) with the `IDENTITY` attribute:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ......
```

With this setup, SQL Server will automatically generate consecutive ID's for your table when rows are being inserted into your table.

With a type `INT`, starting at 1, you get **over 2 billion** possible rows - that should be more than sufficient for the vast majority of cases. With `BIGINT`, you get roughly **922 quadrillion** (922 with 15 zeros - 922'000 billions) - enough for you??

If you use an `INT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert a row every second, you need 66.5 
**years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ....

If you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert one thousand rows every second, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ....

Read more about it (with all the options there are) in the [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

Comment: It seems the thing but what if delete rows is expected? Will they duplicate? And why IDENTITY(1,1) I mean 1,1 is that some period or something?

Comment: If you delete a row, that ID is gone and will **never** be recycled. For the options - read the Books Online; basically, the `(1,1)` means: start at 1, increment by 1

Comment: So it is a random thing, too, or it is an increment thing?

Comment: @user592704: It **increments** steadily - nothing random about it. Starts at one, increments by one (that's the most commonly used default) - 1, 2, 3, 4......... and so forth

Comment: But is it possible to insert randon numbers into id column with some standart function? I mean something like "unpredictable" values? Not the increment but some like a randomly gen. code?

Comment: @user592704: no. The `IDENTITY` columns are handled by SQL Server and will be created in a predictable, steadily incrementing fashion. Those are used as internal "ID's" which should never be visible to outside users anyway. If you need randomness, use GUID's

Comment: Oh, it is quite interesting... But what about products databases? I mean their barcode (a lable code) or something to scan and identify a product price (a shop database)? Is it something else or it can be done with t-sql functions too? I mean a real life row ID example? :)

Comment: @user592704: I have no idea how those unique keys are generated - certainly not with anything built into T-SQL ! There's GUID's for randomness, and INT IDENTITY for steadily increasing key ID's - and that's it. Anything else, you need to roll it on your own (e.g. in a programming language of your choice)

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
T_Id int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
)
```

Here's a link to a tuorial if you are using SQL Server http://howtoideas.net/how-to-create-auto-increment-column-in-a-sql-server-table

Comment: Emm... Isn't it a MySQL thing?